# Why does selecting a custom model result in a violation of type constraints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

Given this model:

```
using X.Models;

namespace X.ViewModels
{

    public struct YRow
    {
        public Y Y { get; set; }
        public YContact LastPhoneCall { get; set; }
        public YContact LastVisit { get; set; }
        public YStatus LastStatus { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I select it via:

```
public IQueryable<YRow> FetchData()
{
    return db.Ys
        .Select(x => new YRow
        {
            Y = x,
            LastPhoneCall = x.Z
                .Where(y => y.Type == YZType.PhoneCall)
                .OrderBy(y => y.Date).LastOrDefault(),
            LastVisit = x.Z
                .Where(y => y.Type == YZType.Visit)
                .OrderBy(y => y.Date).LastOrDefault(),
            LastStatus = x.Statuses.OrderBy(y => y.Date).LastOrDefault(),

        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Y.BusinessName);
}
```

which is passed to an asp:GridView's SelectMethod:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" SelectMethod="FetchData" ItemType="X.ViewModels.YRow">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

When I access the page I get:

> Method System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableHelpers.CountHelper: type
>   argument 'X.ViewModels.YRow' violates the constraint of type parameter
>   'T'.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that the class YRow was defined as a `struct`. Changing it to a `class` made the error go away. There were other issues but this one was solved.